# Get Position of Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, jsplumb, interact.js

I am trying to get the position of an element dropped onto the canvas using the following code.

```
var x = $(".partitiondrop").position();
alert("Top position: " + x.top + "\nLeft position: " + x.left);
```

The above works fine. I would like to know if I can get the Right and Bottom positions in the same way so that I can have the area bound by the element as I need to check which elements fall inside this element.

Comment: getBoundingCientRect()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $partitiondrop = $(".partitiondrop");
var position = $partitiondrop.position();
position.bottom = position.top + $partitiondrop.height();
position.right = position.left + $partitiondrop.width();
alert("Top position: " + position.top + "\nLeft position: " + position.left + "\nBottom position: " + position.bottom + "\nRight position: " + position.right);
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful

Answer (score 3):

U can always add width to x.left position and add height to x.top position.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious, but sameone wrote the post below.

Answer (score 1):

To get the position of any element by its ID you can do the following

```
var elementID; //Already obtained via attr(id) method or so
var $element = $("#" + elementID);
var position = $element.position();
position.bottom = position.top + $element.height();
position.right = position.left + $element.width();

var top_position=position.top;
var left_position=position.left;
var bottom_position=position.bottom;
var right_position=position.right;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery, it can be done using the following code

```
var p = $( "elementId" );
var position = p.position();
$( "p:last" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Position:

```
$(window).width() - ($('.partitiondrop').offset().left + $('.partitiondrop').width());
```

Bottom Position:

```
$(window).height() - $('.partitiondrop').offset().top;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response